# Generating IL for Nullable<T> serialization?

Tags: c#, nullable, reflection.emit, il, conversion-operator

I'm writing my own serializer that emits IL to generate the [de]serialization codes.

For nullables, I thought I could generate the following (take `int?` as an ex) (assuming we already generated methods to [de]serialize `int`):

```
public static void Serialize(Stream stream, int? value, object context)
{
    Serialize(stream, (int)value, context);
}

public static void Deseiralize(Stream stream, out int? value, object context)
{
    int tmp;
    Deserialize(stream, out tmp, context);
    value = tmp;
}
```

Here's how I generate that:

```
    public override void GenSerializationCode(Type type)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var serialize = GetSerializeCall(underlyingType);

        // Serialize(stream, (UnderlyingType)value, context);
        emit.ldarg_0()
            .ldarg_1()
            .unbox_any(underlyingType)
            .ldarg_2()
            .call(serialize)
            .ret();
    }

    public override void GenDeserializationCode(Type type)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var deserialize = GetDeserializeCall(underlyingType);

        // UnderlyingType tmp; Deserialize(stream, out tmp, context);
        var tmp = emit.declocal(underlyingType);
        emit.ldarg_0()
            .ldloca_s(tmp)
            .ldarg_2()
            .call(deserialize);

        // value = tmp;
        emit.ldarg_1()
            .ldloc_s(tmp)
            .stind_ref()
            .ret();
    }
```

I also generate an assembly for debugging. I load it up in ILSpy and the C# code looks exactly like what I had in mind. But peverify had something else to say...

[image]

I thought about it for a minute, then realized that `Nullable<T>` is a struct, so I should use `Ldarga` instead of `Ldarg` so I changed my `ldarg_1()` to `ldarga(1)`

Now peverify gives:

```
[IL]: Error: [C:\Users\vexe\Desktop\MyExtensionsAndHelpers\Solution\CustomSerializer\bin\Release\SerTest.dll : FastSerializer::Serialize][offset 0x00000007][found address of value 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'] Expected an ObjRef on the stack.
```

I thought it's something to do with `Nullable<T>` conversion operators so I tried the `Value` property:

```
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var serialize = GetSerializeCall(underlyingType);
        var getValue = type.GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod();

        // Serialize(stream, value.get_Value(), context);
        emit.ldarg_0()
            .ldarga(1)
            .call(getValue)
            .ldarg_2()
            .call(serialize)
            .ret();
```

peverify is happy about this!

The question is, why didn't the explicit operator from `T` to `Nullable<T>` kick in previously when casting the nullable to its underlying type?

Also, I wasn't able to get rid of the error in Deserialize even when using `Ldarga` instead of `Ldarg` when doing `value = tmp;`- I guess I could try what the implicit conversion is doing. i.e. `value = new Nullable<int>(tmp);` but I would like to find out what I did wrong.

Note: 'emit' is just a helper I use to generate IL. It uses an `ILGenerator` internally and returns itself after each operation so I can chain together calls.

**EDIT:** here's the final code that worked, with notes and all.

```
    // Note:
    // 1- IL doesn't know anything about implicit/explicit operators
    //    so we can't make use of the T to Nullable<T> nor Nullable<T> to T operators
    //    that's why we have to use the Value property when serializing and the ctor when deserializing
    // 2- Nullable<T> is a struct
    //    so we use ldarga when calling the property getter when serializing (the property getter is an instance method, so the first argument is always the 'this', but since we're dealing with structs we have to pass 'this' by ref hence ldarga)
    //    then use stobj opcode when constructing an instance when deserializing

    public override void GenSerializationCode(Type type)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var serialize = ctx.GetSerializeCall(underlyingType);
        var getValue = type.GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod();

        // Serialize(stream, value.get_Value(), ctx);
        emit.ldarg_0()
            .ldarga(1)
            .call(getValue)
            .ldarg_2()
            .call(serialize)
            .ret();
    }

    public override void GenDeserializationCode(Type type)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var deserialize = ctx.GetDeserializeCall(underlyingType);

        // UnderlyingType tmp; Deserialize(stream, out tmp, ctx);
        var tmp = emit.declocal(underlyingType);
        emit.ldarg_0()
            .ldloca_s(tmp)
            .ldarg_2()
            .call(deserialize);

        // value = new Nullable<UnderlyingType>(tmp);
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { underlyingType });
        emit.ldarg_1()
            .ldloc_s(tmp)
            .newobj(ctor)
            .stobj(type)
            .ret();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit and implicit conversions are a purely C# concept.

IL does not have any special awareness of nullable types (except for boxing them into `Object`s); you need to explicitly use `.Value` or call the ctor.

For examples, look at the [IL generated by the C# compiler](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ils/JYOwLg/ABAHg3AKFGWAmKBeKAKZBKeJcaGAZkzTiAAA=).

Answer (score 1):

Operators is only for the C# and VB.NET compilers. IL and IL generations knows nothing about it.